# Does anyone know which component has tmp_object_relations as a table?

Tags: database

Bit of a long shot but does anyone know which Joomla component/plugin/module has tmp_object_relations as a table? I have inherited a site with a lot of components and thought it might be a SobiPro table but apparently not. Looks like a cache table of some sort but it's missing from my DB and I occasionally get the following error.

```
1146 Table 'l-XXXXXX.XXXXXX_tmp_object_relations' doesn't exist SQL=SELECT id FROM `XXXXXX_tmp_object_relations` WHERE pid = '240' ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1000
```

pid will vary depending on the page.

Comment: does the table have no prefix? For example Kunena use `kunena_xxx`. Have you checked the database table to see what kind of data is being stored there? It might give you a better insight as to which extension it belongs to

Comment: if you can't figure it out by table prefix, do "search in files" for ```tmp_object_relations``` to see where it appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This temporary table is used by a **Joomla-SobiPro search plugin** (Extly Extensions, any of the SobiPro search extensions).

It's part of the indexation process. The table is only used temporarily, and no error should be shown. If you have enabled *In Memory temporary tables*, the associated feature may not be available in your database, try to disable them.

*PD: I'm changing the tmp table name to ease debugging ;-) In any case, please, contact us to follow the topic in any of the support channels.*

Comment: I'll chase this through your support channel @Anibal - thanks

Comment: Anibal, this component is on an existing website. As such we don't have our own support package. Is support normally tied to the domain or to the developer?

Comment: Support is only tied to the membership. If you have the original invoice number we can check if the membership is still valid (just contact us in the site)